# Es posible hacer una función para una pagina que se ejecute sin necesidad de abrir mi proyecto PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

Hola tengo esta duda tengo un formulario que guarda productos, fecha de entrada y su fecha de vencimiento y una vez que llega a su fecha de vencimiento elimine ese registro y lo mande a una tabla que se llama **vencido** ya tengo todo esto pero, la cosa es que esta función solo se ejecuta cuando abro el proyecto (**utilizo 2 scripts para que este auto refrescando la tabla y cuando se cumpla la condición elimine e inserte**) y lo que quisiera es que si existe alguna forma que se pueda ejecutar sin necesidad de abrir el proyecto (**si se puede decir internamente**) 
aquí les dejo mi tabla donde se hace la función

```
<?php
  include "conexion.php";

  $actual = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
  $sql = "SELECT Id_produc, Producto, Fecha_entrada, Fecha_expira 
          from producto";
  $resul = $cone->query($sql);
?>
<center>
  <div id="refre">
<table  border=1>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Codigo Producto</th>
            <th>Producto</th>
            <th>Fecha Entrada</th>
            <th>Fecha Expira</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

        <?php while ($row = $resul->fetch_assoc()) 
              {  ?>

                <tr>

                  <td><?php $idpro = $row['Id_produc']; echo $idpro;?></td>
                  <td><?php $pro = $row['Producto']; echo $pro; ?></td>
                  <td><?php echo $row['Fecha_entrada']; ?></td>
                  <td><?php $venci = $row['Fecha_expira']; echo $venci; ?></td>            
                    <?php 
                    if($venci < $actual)
                    {
                      $paz = "DELETE from producto where Id_produc = '$idpro'";
                      $cone->query($paz);

                      $ken = "INSERT INTO vencido (Id_produc, Fecha, Estado) values('$pro', '$actual', 'Vencido')";
                      $cone->query($ken);
                    }
                  ?>  
                </tr>
                <?php }?>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
</center>
```

y este son los scripts que utilizo para que haga el auto refresh

```
<script src="js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var auto_refresh = setInterval(
function ()
{$('#refre').load('cuenta.php').fadeIn("slow");
}, 10000)
</script>
```

Comment: si estas en linux con un CRON sale

Comment: Creo que te estas ahogando en un vaso de agua. No hay necesidad de estar refrescando la pagina constantemente. Esto no es para nada optimo ni una buena practica. Puedes hacer un procedimiento almacenado para tu consulta y antes de devolver los datos realizar esta tarea. Otra opción es usar "jobs" en tu db para hacerlo. [Aquí una idea](http://es.juancarlosmolinos.net/bases-de-datos/mysql/ddl-y-dml/jobs-en-mysql/). Personalmente me quedo con la primer opción. Saludos!

Comment: @FranIslas ok eso hare te lo agradezo

Comment: Apoyo totalmente lo que dice @FranIslas. Tu planteamiento de hacer esto por programación significa renunciar a posibilidades que el manejador de base de datos puede y sabe hacer mucho mejor para aventurarte a hacerlo por ti mismo a nivel de programación.

Comment: No te recomiendo el procedimiento almacenado, tendrías que llamarlo antes de cada consulta, borrado, modificación, en todos los scripts y otros procedimientos almacenados que involucren dichas tablas....   en un ejercicio de practicas funcionará, pero en una aplicación viva puede volver un engorro. Lo habitual es hacer una tarea que diariamente (o semanal o lo que necesites según las especificaciones) actualice esa información.